# How to add a new item to the end of the list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this function for adding a new item to the beginning of the list and removing the last one:

```
function addItem(id, text){
    var el = $('#' + id);
    var w = el.width();
    el.css({
        width:   w,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
    var ulPaddingLeft    = parseInt(el.css('padding-left'));
    var ulPaddingRight = parseInt(el.css('padding-right'));
    el.prepend('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    var first = $('li:first', el);
    var last  = $('li:last',  el);
    var fow = first.outerWidth();
    var widthDiff = fow - last.outerWidth();
    var oldMarginLeft = first.css('margin-Left');
    first.css({
        marginLeft: 0 - fow,
        position:  'relative',
        left:       0 - ulPaddingLeft
    });
    last.css('position', 'relative');
    el.animate({ width: w + widthDiff }, 1500);
    first.animate({ left: 0 }, 250, function() {
        first.animate({ marginLeft: oldMarginLeft }, 1000, function() {
            last.animate({ left: ulPaddingRight }, 250, function() {
                last.remove();

                el.css({
                    width:   'auto',
                    overflow: 'visible'
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

How can I make it work the other way around ? I want to add the item to the end and remove the first and also make it slide the other way around, like right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery.append (and jQuery.prepend for beginning of list)

Comment: Yup, append instead of prepend. And reverse your animations. There's likely a DRY way to have animations go either right or left, but that'd take a pretty generous developer to provide it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems really complicated. Simplifying it a little bit might give you something like this:

```
  $("#whateverList").addItem("awesome")  

 jQuery.fn.addItem = function(text) {
     var $li  = $("<li>").text(text)
     $(this).find("li:first").remove()
     $(this).append($li)
 }
```

1. jQuery plugin syntax is super easy to understand
2. append() to go to the bottom
3. var declarations at the top

Good luck!

Comment: Most of the "complicated" code is to facilitate the animation. Without stepping through everything it does, I can't say if it's overly complicated.